# Custom adapter does not called getVIew

Tags: adapter

Here is the code of my custom adapter... it doesn't call my get view... returns only white blank page without nothing. I don't know what is the problem. Does anybody can help. Thanks a lot previously!

```
   public class ProductShopsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ProductShop> {

    private Context cntx;
    private ArrayList<ProductShop> shopValues;
    ProductShopsHolder holder = null;


    public ProductShopsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,  ArrayList<ProductShop> stringValues) {
        super(context,textViewResourceId);
        shopValues = stringValues;
        cntx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ProductShopsHolder();  

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)cntx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.shops_list, null);

            //Holder Elements initialization
            holder.setShopName((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.shop_name));
            holder.setPrice((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.shop_part_price));

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ProductShopsHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.getShopName().setText(getItem(position).getShopName());
        holder.getPrice().setText(getItem(position).getPrice());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

and here is my XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProductShopsActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:padding="0dp" >
    </ListView>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        layout="@layout/footer_menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and single view :

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f2f2f2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shop_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Technomarket"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shop_part_price"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="30 лв."
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/rightarrow"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Детайли"
        android:textColor="#289bd6"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Comment: ANd i have question marks on classes and XML's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `ArrayList` inside your `ArrayAdapter` - `ArrayAdapter` can store items itself. And that's why `getView()` doesn't get called - default implementation of `getCount()` returns the number of items in `ArrayAdapter` itself. If you keep your items in your own `ArrayList`, at least override `getCount()` to return `shopValues.getCount()`. Otherwise it is always 0 and  the `ListView` to which your adapter is bound doesn't even know there are any items to dsplay at all.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/aragaer/jtt_android/blob/master/src/main/java/com/aragaer/jtt/today/TodayAdapter.java#L102) I use `clear` and `addAll` directly on Adapter object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please check if my post my code? @aragaer